# AWS DMS task is failing with replication task out of memory issue

Tags: aws-dms

AWS DMS task is failing with

> Last Error Replication task out of memory. Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

To give background, I have created a new replication instance with 100 GB allocated memory and dms.r5.large instance class. Created a replication task using the new replication instance replicated 15 tables the size of data is a maximum of 8 GB.

When I start the task it's failing with the above-mentioned error. I have checked in the cloud watch logs, it doesn't show any specific error details.